# how to get the values from Jsonstringify using angular4?

Tags: json, angular, stringify

I have tried like this from the response:

```
{success: true, result: {picture: "picture-1529913236852.jpg"}}
```

I need to get picture only from `jsonstringify`, Here is my code:

```
this.http.post('myurl', uploadData)
.subscribe(res =>{
    console.log("meee"+JSON.stringify(res));
    this.imageResp = JSON.stringify(res.picture) // here i cant take my picture values
});
```

please Help me.

Comment: Can you share what is the typeof response using typeof(res)?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need JSON.stringify since its already an object,

just use

```
this.imageResp = res.result.picture;
```

Comment: you need res.result.picture

Comment: i dont know the format to get picture seperate as you said

Comment: @SelvaMeena before fetching from `res.result.picture` you could check if the returned json actually has a `picture`.